# MockMVC adds additional quotes with string in request param with post request

Tags: java, spring, junit5, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

MockMvc adds quotes at the ends of string when passed in `param()` in request builder like following

```
// initialization of mockMvc
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();

ObjectNode tweets = ((ObjectNode) result.getRequest().getAttribute("tweets"));

String query = tweets.get("query").toString();
String nextToken = tweets.get("meta").get("next_token").toString();

mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/next")
                    .param("query", query)
                    .param("next_token", nextToken)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.isError", is("N")))
                    .andReturn();
```

if query is `"#GoGreen"` and next_token is `"wefw234234ewf234"` are received in controller is
query = `"\"#GoGreen\""` and next_token = `"\"wefw234234ewf234\""`

```
    @PostMapping("/next") @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> nextPageTrendingTweets(@RequestParam("query") String query,
                                                         @RequestParam("next_token") String nextToken)
```

Maybe I'm missing something when initializing `mockMvc`. I searched about this problem but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with mockMvc but it is with how you're extracting data from `ObjectNode` "tweets". You've used `.toString()` method to get string data. However, it is incorrect because `ObjectNode.get()` method returns object and `.toString()` converts it into string representation that's why extra quotes. So the solution of the problem is use `ObjectNode.get().asText()` method which will return that exact string in the object without any modification or conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment part (`#foo`) lives entirely inside the browser and is not passed in HTTP requests. Don't send it at all.

Comment: I didn't get anything you're saying. Can you elaborate more with a example?